# Place is not showing up in Google Maps - search leads to a different place

Tags: google-maps

I've got a client who has discovered that searching for their community centre in Google Maps leads to a nearby church, and not to their own centre.  They've asked me to look into this, and I haven't a clue what's going on!

The church that the search leads to doesn't appear to share a name with the centre, although it is nearby. I've created a Google map for the centre website, with the name and location correctly marked - I thought that might help, but it hasn't.

Anyone have any ideas how I can direct the search to the right place?

Comment: What are you currently doing?  What is the wrong place? What is the right place?

Comment: Start by creating a place for the community center: https://www.google.de/business/placesforbusiness/

Comment: Thanks, I just did that - hopefully that will solve it!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Dr Molle, for pointing me to the places registration! Hopefully that'll solve it!